# groovy How to extract string?

Tags: string, groovy, extract

(groovy) I have a string like "1.2.3" and I have to extract the substring before the last "." for example "1.2" . I tried some split('.'), tokenize('.'), but they don't work.

Comment: `split( /\./ )` should work

Answer (score 0):

How about the below?

```
def v = "1.2.3"
v.substring(0, v.lastIndexOf("."))
```